# Adding another condition with already existing Reqular expression

Tags: javascript

I just tried to frame a regular expression for allowing negative and non-negative integer values. It is working fine,

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[-]?\\d+$');
```

But now i'm confused in adding two more constraints with it, That is to allow lowercase `a` and overall digits should be less than or equal to `2` and greater than or equal to `1`. Can anybody help me in achieving that.?

### [DEMO of what i have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/LZf7H/402/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in JavaScript, it's usually best to use the literal form of regex rather than strings, because you don't have to do double escaping. It's a lot less confusing.

So your literal rex is:

```
var regex = /^[-]?\d+$/;
```

Before we add the conditions: The character class `[-]` is pointless, you just match that one character `-`:

```
var regex = /^-?\d+$/;
// Here ------^
```

You've said you want to allow `a` in there, so you need a character class:

```
var regex = /^-?[a\d]+$/;
// Here --------^^^^^
```

And you've said you want the length to be 1-2 characters. I'm going to assume that doesn't include the optional `-`, so you need a different quantifier:

```
var regex = /^-?[a\d]{1,2}$/;
// Here -------------^^^^^
```

Here's that regex thoroughly explained:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `-?` matches the character `-` literally

  - Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `[a\d]{1,2}` match a single character present in the list below

  - Quantifier: Between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - `a` the literal character a (case sensitive)
  - `\d` match a digit [0-9]
- `$` assert position at end of the string

[Live Copy](http://regex101.com/r/gN2zK9)

---

From your comment below:

> how can i change it to accept either a or numbers, meaning not both at the same time. and including - symbol it should have a length less than 2.

So you're saying `-a` is a valid input, and `aa` is a valid input, but not `-aa` (because it's too long).

Because you need to apply different quantifiers depending on whether the `-` is present, you're probably best off with an alternation (`|`):

```
var regex = /^(?:(?:-[a\d])|(?:[a\d]{1,2}))$/
```

We need the non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) because alternations apply to the broadest condition they can, and we want the `^` and `$` to be outside the alternation.

[Explained](http://regex101.com/r/zM7uR9):

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `(?:(?:-[a\d])|(?:[a\d]{1,2}))` Non-capturing group

  - 1st Alternative: `(?:-[a\d])`

    - `(?:-[a\d])` Non-capturing group

      - `-` matches the character `-` literally
      - `[a\d]` match a single character present in the list below

        - `a` the literal character `a` (case sensitive)
        - `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`
  - 2nd Alternative: `(?:[a\d]{1,2})`

    - `(?:[a\d]{1,2})` Non-capturing group

      - `[a\d]{1,2}` match a single character present in the list below

        - Quantifier: Between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        - `a` the literal character `a` (case sensitive)
        - `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`
- `$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: +1 for such a detailed explanation, how can i change it to accept either `a` or `numbers`, meaning not both at the same time. and including `-` symbol it should have a length less than 2. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: I think you'd need an alternation for that, see update above. Also, I missed that `[-]` thing earlier, that character class doesn't do anything, just use `-` (also updated above). I think that should get you going the right way. Best,

Comment: Thnks for the info. Thanks.!